# Is a symmetric positive definite matrix similar to a triadiagonal symmetric positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, positive-definite

Is any real symmetric positive definite matrix similar to a triadiagonal symmetric positive definite matrix?

From Householder lemma it is known that if $B$ is symmetric, there exists a orthogonal matrix $H$ such that $C=H^\top B H$ is triadiagonal symmetric. The question is whether $C$ is definite positive; it has the same (positive) eigenvalues as $B$ so I would say yes.

Is this correct?

Comment: I think you are correct - as far as I know if a symmetric matrix has all positive eigenvalues then it is positive definite. But I don't know how to verify it.